# Как должна быть сделана сортировка при клике по по заголовку столбца в Vaadin Table?

Tags: java, vaadin

Есть **vaadin**-таблица **Table** которая отображает содержимое таблицы БД при помощи SQL-запроса.

Проблема в том, что при клике по заголовку столбца таблицы я вижу то стрелочку вверх (типа сортировка по возрастанию), то стрелочку вниз (по убыванию). Но самой сортировки почему то не происходит. о_О

Скажите пожалуйста, эта сортировка должна быть на уровне Table Vaadin (но я что-то забыл указать) или это просто "бутафорские" )) стрелочки, и никакой сортировки не предполагается и мне нужно писать отдельный обработчик клика и "подсовывать" **select** с **order by** ???